# Can we get at the previous value with fluent validation?

Tags: blazor, fluentvalidation

I'm using the [`Blazored.FluentValidation`](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation) package in a Blazor server-side project. That package uses the [`FluentValidation`](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation) package to do the actual validation.

One of my validators has a custom rule that calls the Google Maps API to validate a UK postcode. This works fine, but fires every time the rule fires, which causes a network call (incurring a delay in the validation), and ramps up my API usage.

Is there a way of checking if the postcode value has actually changed, so I can only make the API call if it has? I can't see any way of getting a previous value from the validator.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could add a property to your model (IsPostCodeDirty), set it onchange and then change your Rule to use `.When(x => x.IsPostCodeDirty)`.

Comment: I think that falls outside the concern of your validator if you're making an api call during validation. You could try caching your response from google with the postcode as the key and return the same result to the validator without making the request, for instance. Then your validator can just worry about the validation.